# Debian 9 доступ к выделенному серверу только по SSH для www пользователя

Tags: linux, debian, ssh-key, openssh

Моя цель, сделать подключение к выделенному серверу с установленной Debian 9  только по SSH ключу и с запретом для root.

- добавил публичный ключ на сервер командой echo "ВАШ_КЛЮЧ" >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
- создал пользователя www и  добавил его в группу sudo зашел под этим пользователем
- изменил файл конфигурации sshd_config

  AllowUsers www
  PermitRootLogin no
  PasswordAuthentication no
- Перезапустил ssh

при подключении пишет  Permission denied (publickey).
Подскажите что может быть?

Comment: Вы не добавили публичный ключ для пользователя www

Comment: @andreymal я пробовал менять команду echo "ВАШ_КЛЮЧ" >> /www/.ssh/authorized_keys  но не получилось, подскажите как правильно составить команды для этого пользователя

Comment: /home/www видимо. Вам нужно изучить основы линукса

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, понял, обязательно изучу

Comment: @andreymal  мне нужно создать категорию .ssh в папке www ?